# Finding the area of a similar triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I tried to use trigonometry to find the area but I did not find a formula. How can I can find the area of this triangle?

[image]

Comment: Hint:  the triangles are similar

Answer (score 1):

Hint

If the hypotenuse, the base $=h,b$ respectively,

We have $$\dfrac{h(1.3)}2=\dfrac{b(1.5)}2$$ both being area of the triangle

$h/15=b/13=k$(say)

Again $$(15k)^2-(13k)^2=(1.5)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Note the side length of the small right triangle is $\sqrt{1.5^2-1.3^2}=\frac{\sqrt{14}}5 $ and its area $\frac12( 1.3)\frac{\sqrt{14}}5=\frac{13\sqrt{14}}{100} $. Then, proportionally, the area of the large triangle

$$ \left( \frac{1.5}{\frac{\sqrt{14}}5}\right)^2\left(\frac{13\sqrt{14}}{100}\right)
=\frac{117}{224}\sqrt{14}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Denote the hypotenuse by $h$ and the unknown leg by $l$. By Pythagoras and [Inverse Pythagoras](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Pythagorean_theorem), we have $$h^2=2.25+l^2 \\ \frac{1}{1.69} = \frac{1}{2.25} +\frac{1}{l^2}$$ Yielding $l=2.605, h=4.855$ and the area $=6.323$ sq. units.